# Question about AWS S3 + Cloudfront + ACM + Route 53 (Static website DNS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I am trying to use AWS S3 Busket, Route 53, and Cloudfront to host a static website.
I also issued SLL using ACM. I am having some issues with the subdomain 'www', root seems to be working.

Here are the details:

## **S3 Bucket:**

- **Bucket location: US West (Oregon) us-west-2**
- Publicly accessible
- Static website hosting
- Block all public access if off
- Using the following policy:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- ALC: Bucket owner (Objects=List, Write | Bucket ACL = Read, Write)
- All objects have been made public using ACL

## **ACM:**

- Created a certificate in **US East (N. Virginia) us-east-1**
- Made sure to add both my root and sub domain to certificate (example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

## **Cloudfront:**

- Created a distribution using Cloudfront
- Applied the certificate to it
- Supported HTTP version = HTTP/2

## **Route 53**

- Created a hosted zone
- Assigned the Alias to point to the CloudFront distribution

This is where I think the problem started.
Since the certificate was in us-east-1, I could not create a record in Route 53 directly from ACM. So I manually added CNAMEs for root and subdomain in Route 53.

Then I copied the DNS to my domain provider (Google domains).

Now I an seeing the `https://example.com` seems to work but `https://www.example.com` still gives error.

Am I doing some thing wrong here?

Thanks